# Showing bibliography as an example

Tags: bibliographies

I want to create a showcase bibliography (with only one entry) in the middle of the document. I have tried having a separate bib file, with only this entry and `\nocite` command, but it creates a ToC item, which i don't want. `\bibliography*{}` doesen't work at all. I've tried also `\begin{thebibliography}` but it is also not working.

The code is here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

\section{bibliography example}
This is the bibliography example:
%i want to get it here
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sample}
\nocite{*}
```

The Sample file looks like this:

```
@book {H2G2,
  author = {Douglas Adams},
  title = "Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy",
  chapter = "5",
  pages = "42",
  year = "1996",
}
```

If I run it without `\nocite{*}` command, i get an error, because I don't have any citations.
But if I run it with the command, it compiles, but I get a new section and ToC entry, which I don't want.
So if I edit the command to be `\bibliography*{sample}` it says:

```
I couldn't open database file *.bib
---line 46 of file main.aux
 : \bibdata{*
 :           }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

Comment: Statements such as "doesn't work at all" and "it is also not working" aren't exactly specific. Please post some actual LaTeX code showing what precisely you've tried. Please also tell us which document class you and which citation management packages (if any) you load.

Comment: @Mico I have added MWE and explained the problem more in detail, is it OK now?

Comment: @Mico the sample file is in the same dir as the main. As stated, if I try only with `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and `\bibliography{sample}` it compiles and it works, but i get ToC entry, which I do not want.

Comment: @Mico I am creating a document on TeX. I want to have a bibliography example in the middle of it and complete bibliography at the end.

Comment: Basically, then, the "bibliography example in the middle" isn't a bibliography at all -- at least not in the usual sense of the word. Why don't you just hand-format the example "entry" and be done with it?

Comment: @Mico I haven't thought of that... That will be great! Thanks for all the time!